# how to embed a text image in a background image in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, text

I am trying to embed a text in a background image using python. The background image is 1.jpg and the text image is 2.jpg. The background image contains a wall on which I want to embed the text region 2.jpg which contains scene text "Poppins". Can anybody help me out with the code?

The sample input is given

[image]

The sample output is somewhat like this:

[image]

Though I have doe it with paint!! Originally the sample output should look like this where natural scene text is embedded in the background of the image

[image]

Sample Text Image is:

[image]

Which is an extracted scene text

Comment: Please attach the sample input images and expected output images ?

Comment: Okay I have attached it!

Comment: Where's the actual text image?  Why can't you simply just **write** the actual text in the image?  OpenCV has actual methods to write text in images.

Comment: If you want to *"overlay"* text onto images, people normally use PNG files with transparent backgrounds so that you don't get a big ugly lump of background when overlaying. But as Ray says, why not write the text on the image?

Comment: @MarkSetchell because I want to embed scene text on background images to make it look more realistic

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. There must be something about the text that we can't see. Please provide a representative example of the text image. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have provided the sample natural scene text. Hope my aim will be clear to you now. I want to embed such sample text in the background of the image(here background is the wall) as realistically as possible.Thanks

Comment: Ok, and how do you expect that to look when overlaid? Please show an expected result image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have included the expeceted result image. Kindly revisit the question.

Comment: So you overlay the word `shop` onto a creamy picture of a clock and, as a result, you get some completely different words on a red wall beside a mirror? I am voting to close this question on the grounds it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think my question is not clear. I would not post this question if I already have overlaid the word onto a picture of clock. The sample output that I have given is some already available data set. I want to add my own data to expand the data set. Hope this helps. Nevertheless I have already got a relevant answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to paste one image on top of another, your text file should be a .png file (so that the overlay file contains no background data), then you can use the following code, importing the PIL library:

```
from PIL import Image

image1 = Image.open('img1.jpg')
image2 = Image.open('img2.png')

image1.paste(image2, (0,0))

image1.show()
```

Change the (0,0) values to move the png text image around on x,y co-ordinates.

Comment: I guess someone did it by mistake because it's now no more there. Thanks! It worked for me. By the way if you could suggest something to make the text more realistic?

Comment: The image needs to have an alpha channel for it to look more realistic.